# ArcObjects Export Field with x y gives InvalidCastException?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I am try to export field and X Y but I get the following error. Is it possible for someone to help me with this?

> system.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint'. 
>   This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 
>   '{1B077915-38C5-11D0-92D2-00805F7C28B0}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The Code:

```vb
Dim delimiter As String = ","
Dim aFileName As String
aFileName = "c:\log.txt"
Dim pPt As IPoint

FileOpen(1, aFileName, OpenMode.Output, OpenAccess.Default, OpenShare.Shared)

' Get first layer in map which is the annotation layer
Dim pMXDocument As IMxDocument
'  pMXDocument = My.ArcMap.Document.ActiveView
pMXDocument = My.ArcMap.Document

Dim pMap As IMap
pMap = pMXDocument.FocusMap
Dim pLayer As ILayer
pLayer = pMap.Layer(0)
Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
pFeatureLayer = pLayer

' Create a cursor
Dim pFtrCsr As IFeatureCursor
pFtrCsr = pFeatureLayer.Search(Nothing, False)

' loop printing text string
Dim s As String
Dim pFtr As IFeature
pFtr = pFtrCsr.NextFeature
Do While Not pFtr Is Nothing
   ' On Error Resume Next
    pPt = pFtr.Shape

    s = CStr(pFtr.Value(pFtr.Fields.FindField("TEXTSTRING"))) + "," + CStr(pPt.X) + "," + CStr(pPt.Y)

    '  s = pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("TEXTSTRING"))
    '  Debug.Print(s)

    WriteLine(1, s)

    pFtr = pFtrCsr.NextFeature
Loop

FileClose(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are assuming your annotation is a point which is causing an invalid cast exception.

If you cast your `pFtr` into an `IAnnotationFeature2` you can get to the geometry of the **Element**.

```
Dim pAnnotationFeature2 As IAnnotationFeature2
pAnnotationFeature2 = pFtr
msgbox(str(pAnnotationFeature2.Annotation.Geometry.GeometryType))
```

In my test data it was returning a 3 for geometry type which is a polyline. I don't know if an Annotation geometry is always a polyline, may be someone else can confirm this?